# Approach Problem, Probability: Defective item detection.

Tags: probability

The question is:

*A batch of one hundred items is inspected by testing four randomly selected items. If one of the four is defective, the batch is rejected. What is the probability that the batch is accepted if it contains five defectives?*

$A_{i}$ is the event that a batch is containing $i$ defective items.

P$(A_{i})$ = $\frac{100 \choose i}{2^{100}}$ 
B is selecting 4 items. C finding none of the items defective.

P$(B \cap C | A_5)$ = $\frac{\frac{95 \choose 4}{2^{100}}}{\frac{100 \choose 5}{2^{100}}}$ = $\frac{95 \choose 4}{100 \choose 5}$

I want to ask what is the problem with this approach. I've seen other method which I understand reasonably.

Comment: I do not understand why this question was downvoted (even twice now). At least give a reason for that.

Comment: How did you come to your formula for $P(A_i)$? The RHS is not depending on $i$ so it cannot be correct.

Comment: @drhab, I do not understand why this question was not closed as duplicate post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787457/probability-defective-item-detection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Probability: Defective item detection.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1787457/probability-defective-item-detection)

Comment: @MithleshUpadhyay It is asked here: "what is the problem with this approach?". And the approach is definitely not the same as in the former question. In my view this is not a duplicate question. Someone is struggling with probability. Help him out (instead of downvotes)!

Comment: @drhab I've edited the $P(A_i)$.

Comment: You know **nothing** about the quality of the batches. How then can you know the probability that it contains $i$ defective items?

Comment: @drhab Do you think that's the problem with this approach.

Comment: It is an essential mistake (made at the start). So reason enough to know that the approach won't work. Leave it aside and have a good look at the link in the comment of @MithleshUpadhyay.

Comment: @drhab thank you for your help. Appreciate it.

Comment: You are very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result of a correct approach:$$\frac{\binom50\binom{95}4}{\binom{100}4}=\frac{\binom{95}4}{\binom{100}4}$$

The probability that the $4$ selected items all belong to the $95$ that are not defect.